# Multiple rows added on html table via ajax. Now, how to save them with one shot?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple .html.erb view with a html table with 2 columns: customer, book.

This view has a button which opens a modal with 2 selects (one for customer, the other to book) and a "Add" button. Clicking on it, the modal closes and a new entry is appended on table via ajax.

Every action is not persisted on database.

In the end of the view, there is a "Save" button who needs to parse all actions on table and, now, save them on database.

The ajax handling works perfectly, here is the code:

```
# transfer.html.erb
<a href="#" class="ls-btn-primary" data-ls-module="modal" data-target="#new_action">Add</a>
<table class="ls-table" id='action_table'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>Book</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>

# action_controller.rb
def new_action
  @action = Action.new(customer: customer, book: book)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

# _append_action.html.erb
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= @action.customer.name %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= @action.book.name %>
  </td>
  <td>
</tr>

#application.js
$('#new_action').on('click', function() {
  var url = "/actions/new";

  $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
    },
    type:     'POST',
    url:      url,
    dataType: 'script',
    data:     {
      "book" : $("#book_id").val(),
      "customer" : $("#customer_id").val()
    },
    success: function(e) {
      locastyle.modal.close("#new_action");
    }
  });
});
```

My question is, what is the best way to persist all actions added by the user? Everything what he wants is on the table.

I was wondering to set a global variable on controller to add the actions every time the user clicks on "Add" button in modal, but the idea seems a bad smell.

Anyone has a better idea?

Any help will be really appreciated! :)

Comment: it can be done by setting up js object array , looping each row in object and sending it to server via ajax -- best if you parse it into json and send it, Also i am not particularly sure about your question

Comment: @parladneupane you mean on the save button, fetch somehow all actions on table via jquery and persist them? My question is, I have all actions that needs to be persisted in a html table, what is the best way to get and persist them in the database?